# How to change the color of submenu in CSS but not the parent menu when hover?

Tags: css

I have a menu that uses a script for drop down. The problem is I want set the menu such that when I hover on the parent alone, it changes color which I have done successfully already but when I hover on the sub menu, I do not want the parent to change color, just the sub menu alone. Because whenever I try to hover on the sub menu, the parent menu will automatically be hovered over too together with the sub menu I hovered over. I think because the sub menu is part of the parent.

Is it possible to separate their hovering effects such that the parent menu changes color when hovered alone but does not change when its sub menu is hovered instead?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You forgot to post your code.  And a JSFiddle illustrating your problem will attract more people willing to help you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In addition to what @SteveWellens said please provide some example of what you have tried to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is this:

```
parent:hover child{
  background: ???
}
```

when you hover over the parent just give the child the color of your choice

e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/WL3LY/

Comment: I think he wants the parent to not change color when the child is being hovered

Comment: Yes, Vic is correct. However, I have found what the problem was. Instead of putting the effect on the list, I put the effect on the link inside the list. Thank you! I will post codes the next time I post a question! :)